# Dynamically push elements into an array [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, web, maps

```
var stops = [
  {
    "Geometry": {
      "Latitude":52.1615470947258,
      "Longitude":20.80514430999756
    }
  },
  //next element of the same sort
]
```

I want to push elements into this array using javascript.  How do I do this?

Comment: What is the problem over here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
stops.push(elements);
```

Comment: I'm new to programming. what are the parameters should i pass to inside push to get the exact array order?

Comment: @user1617207 The internet has lots of example on this topic.

Comment: @user1617207 - [MDN provides great references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) if you need to know how to use a certain method.

Answer (score 0):

This one does not help in your case?

```
var stops = [{"Geometry":"Latitude":52.1615470947258,"Longitude":20.80514430999756}},next element of the same sort}]

var newStops = {"Geometry2":{"Latitude":52.1615470947258,"Longitude":20.80514430999756}}

stops.push(newStops)
```